# Discord.py command say in channel or in set channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been testing the "say" command and tried to configure it to send message to a certain channel using the #channel,the problem is that when I don't write the channel: "! Say text", in the console it keeps showing me that I need to put a channel, how can I change the variable "channel" when the channel is not written. Thnx for reading.

```py
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel,* , message):
    if not channel:
        channel=()
    embed=discord.Embed(
        description=(message),
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: what do you want to do? this code looks fine to me. it's just missing `)` at the end of line 7

Comment: The problem is that when I don't write the channel: "! Say text", in the console it keeps showing me that I need to put a channel, how can I change the variable "channel" when the channel is not written.

Error in line 7 fixed. thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, message):
    args = message.split(' ')
    channel = args[0]
    if type(channel) is not discord.TextChannel:
        channel = ctx.channel
    else:
        message = message.replace(channel,'')
    embed=discord.Embed(
        description=(message),
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: The problem is that when I don't write the channel: "! Say text", in the console it keeps showing me that I need to put a channel, how can I change the variable "channel" when the channel is not written.

Comment: If you are putting that in parameter then it is required, @J0ssue. Check the updated answer for the new solution.

Comment: When I use my code it shows me this in the console [link](https://imgur.com/a/nsH5st7) ,then when I add the modifications, i can no longer send messages to other channels using "#channel" [link](https://imgur.com/a/JwoWMTH)